# How to match nodes which have ALL nodes in another sequence

Tags: xslt, xpath

We're using **XSLT2**. Wondering if this is possible.

We have a tag filter, where a customer can choose to see all the themes which match **ALL** of their selections.

Here's an idea of the XML structure:

```
<themes>
   <theme>
      <name>Apple</name>
      <tags>
         <tag id="1">
         <tag id="2">
      </tags>
   </theme>
   <theme>
      <name>Banana</name>
      <tags>
         <tag id="2">
         <tag id="3">
      </tags>
   </theme>
   <theme>
      <name>Kiwifruit</name>
      <tags>
         <tag id="2">
         <tag id="3">
      </tags>
   </theme>
</themes>
```

The customer chooses tags 2 and 3. The result we want is to only show is Banana and Kiwifruit, as they have all the tags the user selected.

We can't use the AND operator as the list of tags is long and unknown. We currently have this list passed into the XSLT and then tokenised:

```
<xsl:param name="tag_ids"/>   
<xsl:variable name="tag_id_list" select="tokenize($tag_ids,',')"/>
```

This statement selects any theme that has any of the tag_id_list:

```
<xsl:for-each select="themes/theme/tags/tag[@id=$tag_id_list]">
```

But we're trying to find a XPath statement that makes sure the  has ALL the s in $tag_id_list

Any ideas?! Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give an example of the data that is passed into the param "tag_ids"

Comment: Yes, that would just be tag_ids = '2,3' in this example

Comment: If just '2' was entered as a tag, should all the fruits be shown, as they all have a '2', or would none be shown, because of them having additional tags which were not entered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this if the tags have to be in the right order:

```
themes/theme/tags[deep-equal($tag_id_list, tag/@id)]
```

or this if they can be in any order:

```
themes/theme/tags[
  (every $tag in $tag_id_list satisfies $tag = tag/@id)
    and
  (every $tag in tag/@id satisfies $tag = $tag_id_list)]
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I only needed the first part of that expression (every $tag in $tag_id_list satisfies $tag = tag/@id), as I also wanted to find Banana and Kiwifruit if I just passed in '3'. Works a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You could count the number of tags that match, and see if it equals to the number of tags in `tag_id_list`. For example

```
    <xsl:variable name="tagcount" select="count($tag_id_list)" />
    <xsl:for-each select="themes/theme[count(tags/tag[@id=$tag_id_list]) = $tagcount]">
```

If the customer could enter duplicate tags (like '2,2,3') then you might have to change `tagcount` to this

```
<xsl:variable name="tagcount" select="count(distinct-values($tag_id_list))" />
```